# How to compare two sheets row wise with different no. of rows in both the sheets. Sheet1 should be compared with specific no of rows in Sheet2

Tags: excel, compare

I'm new to macro designing. I have two sheets in an excel sheet and both need to be compared row wise. The problem is that my first sheet contains 10 data rows but the other sheet has around 1000 rows. I need to compare my data(10 rows) in `sheet1` with a specific number of rows in the `sheet2` on the basis of date.

How do I fetch these specific number of rows?
And also, once compared, the differences should be highlighted and pasted into a new sheet named `sheet3`.

Comment: Writing some code is always a good start. What have you tried so far?

Comment: This could probably also be done without using macros. Just use the `vlookup` function. Functions can also be used between worksheets (and even workbooks).